# PHP stdClass question

Tags: php, stdclass

Scenario:

```
$x = json_decode( $x );
foreach ( $x as $item )
{
    $info[] = $item;  //ERROR
}
```

I am looping though a datafeed to get the data.  I want to add items to a stdClass object in a loop.  How would I do that?  I'm not that familiar with stdobj's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expect the json_decode to return an array, you could do the following:

```
$x = json_decode( $x, true ); // returns associative array instead of object
$info = (object) $x;
```

More info and examples can be found [here](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/).

Comment: May I point out that you're casting an object to an object? That doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: Good catch! Fixed the code so that it returns an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you should just be able to follow regular object syntax to get the result you want.  Add the optional second parameter to `json_decode` set to `true` to get your json decoded as an associative array, as it seems as if this is the form that you're using it in.

```
$info = new stdClass();
$x = json_decode( $x, true );
foreach ( $x as $key => $val) { 
    $info->$key = $val;
}
```

As Ignas pointed out though, the results of `json_decode()` already come back as a stdClass object, so if you just used `$x = json_decode($x)`, you wouldn't need `$info` at all... you'd already have `$x` as a stdClass object.

Answer (score 1):

`SPL`'s [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) let's you use the same syntax that generates an error in your example. This is provided you have the ability to use an `ArrayObject` instead of a `stdClass`.